# Difference between htpasswd and passwd

Tags: apache2, passwd

What is the difference between htpasswd and passwd when setting passwords for users?

Comment: is that a question? htpasswd is for apache passwd/authentication system while passwd is for unix/like system passwords.

Comment: Of course it is a question.  What is confusing about my question?

Comment: Upvoted your comment.  Put it in as an answer for rep

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

Passwd for unix like systems:

```
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd
```

Httpasswd for apache:

```
 https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html
```